# Socket stress test

Tags: c, linux, sockets, libpcap

What will flood the network better?

1- Opening one socket to http web server and write data till crash

2- Openning multiple sockets and write data till crash

3- Opening a socket and send tcp packets till crash

4- Opening multiple sockets and send tcp packets till crash ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like what you are looking to do is to test how the web server reacts to various flavors of Denial of Service attacks.

Something to consider is what is the Denial of Service logic in the web server and how is Denial of Service protection typically implemented in web servers.  For instance is there logic to cap the number of concurrent connections or the number of concurrent connections from the same IP or to monitor the amount of traffic so as to throttle it or to disconnect if the amount of traffic exceeds some threshold.

One thing to consider is to not just push lots of bytes through the TCP/IP socket.  The web server is interpreting the bytes and is expecting the HTTP protocol to be used.  So what happens if you do strange and unusual things with the HTTP protocol as well as other protocols that are built onto HTTP.

For options 3 and 4 it sounds like you are considering bypassing the TCP/IP stack with its windowing logic and to just send a stream of TCP protocol packets ignoring reply packets until something smokes.  This would be more of a test of the TCP stack robustness on the server rather than the robustness of the web server itself.

Answer (score 2):

The ability to reach network saturation depends on network conditions. It is possible to write your "flooder" in such a way that it slows you down because you are causing intermediate devices to drop packets, and the server itself ends up not seeing its maximum load.

Your application should start with one connection, and monitor the data rate. Continue to add connections if the aggregate data rate for all connections continues to rise. Once it no longer rises, you have hit a throughput limit. If it starts to drop, you are exceeding capacity of your system, and are either causing congestion control to kick in, or the server is unable to efficiently handle that many connections. If the throughput limit is much lower than what you expected, then you probably need to debug your network, or tune your TCP/socket parameters. If it is the server that is slowing down, you will need to profile it to see why it is not able to handle the connection load.

Also, check the data rate of each connection, and see if certain connections are much faster than others. If that happens, then the server has a fairness problem which should also be addressed. This has less to do with server and network performance as it has to do with good user experience, though. The presence of such a problem could be exploited in a denial of service attack.